# Delphi 7 - split string with strict delimiter without using new procedures

Tags: string, delphi, split, delphi-7, tstringlist

I need to split the following string into a `TStringList` using `'|'` as the only `Delimiter`:

```
" 0.985,EError can't find,E| 0,5186,Name,6946"
```

Then I need to split each `TStringList` item using `','` as the only `Delimiter.

So, in the first `TStringList` would be these items:

```
" 0.985,EError can't find,E"
"0,5186,Name,6946"
```

Then, in the second `TStringList` would be these items:

```
" 0.985"
"ERror can't find"
"E"
```

I have to do it without new procedures.

Comment: This question has been asked many times. Try a websearch.

Comment: *"I have to do it without new procedures."* - What kind of a requirement is that?

Answer (score 4):

What you are asking for requires the `StrictDelimiter` property, which did not exist yet in Delphi 7.  Without the `StrictDelimiter` property, the `DelimitedText` property setter includes spaces as delimiters regardless of the `Delimiter` property, and you cannot change that behavior.  So, you will have to parse the input string manually instead.

The following code is derived from the `StrictDelimiter` logic used in later Delphi versions, and works fine in Delphi 7:

```
uses
  SysUtils, Classes, Windows;

procedure SplitDelimitedText(const Value: string; List: TStrings; StrictDelimiter: Boolean = True);
var
  P, P1: PChar;
  S: string;
begin
  if not StrictDelimiter then
  begin
    List.DelimitedText := Value;
    Exit;
  end;

  List.BeginUpdate;
  try
    List.Clear;
    P := PChar(Value);
    while P^ <> #0 do
    begin
      if P^ = List.QuoteChar then
        S := AnsiExtractQuotedStr(P, List.QuoteChar)
      else
      begin
        P1 := P;
        while (P^ <> #0) and (P^ <> List.Delimiter) do
          P := CharNext(P);
        SetString(S, P1, P - P1);
      end;
      List.Add(S);

      if P^ = List.Delimiter then
      begin
        P1 := P;
        if CharNext(P1)^ = #0 then
          List.Add('');
        P := CharNext(P);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    List.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

```
var
  s: String;
  sl1, sl2: TStringList;
  i: Integer;
begin;
  s := ' 0.985,EError can''t find,E| 0,5186,Name,6946';
  sl1 := TStringList.Create;
  try
    sl1.Delimiter := '|';
    sl1.QuoteChar := #0;
    SplitDelimitedText(s, sl1);

    sl2 := TStringList.Create;
    try
      sl2.Delimiter := ',';
      sl2.QuoteChar := #0;
      for I := 0 to sl1.Count-1 do
      begin
        SplitDelimitedText(sl1[i], sl2);
        // use sl2 as needed...
      end;
    finally
      sl2.Free;
    end;
  finally
    sl1.Free;
  end;
end;
```